# How do I change a CSS class per @media screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I have a simple div box with text i want to format differently depending on if the user is viewing in desktop/tablet/laptop or mobile device. I am trying to use `@media screen` but maybe I'm doing it wrong. Here is what I tried:

```
.topbox {
position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topbox {
    background: #9b4fe0;
    width: 300px;
        }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.topbox {
    background: #ff5000;
    width: 600px;
        }
}
```

In my head I have:
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: can you show us what you have tried, ang show some sample code.

Comment: Does your topbox is a class ? because if it is , please notice that you're using # inside the media queries and you should change it to .topbox

Comment: Ok whoops, i fixed it.

Comment: does it works now ? @mlolm

Comment: Sort of @BarLevin - It is not displaying correct properties but it must be how i have setup max-width.

Comment: It should be working fine , try play a bit with the widthes. but your media query should work and change colors atleast

Comment: Because of the way CSS works, `max-width: 800` will override your `max-width: 600`, since the `max-width: 800` condition will still be met. You should change those to either `min-width` or set up `(min-width:) and (max-width)` combined rules.

Comment: You can also take Johannes answer and just flip those to rules around, so make the `800` rule first.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code you have:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topbox {
    background: #9b4fe0;
    width: 300px;
        }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.topbox {
    background: #ff5000;
    width: 600px;
        }
}
```

With this code, the second media query will overwrite the first one - it follows after it *and*  everything that's less than 800px is also less than 600px, so the 600px rule won't have any effect. To fix that, just turn around their order:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.topbox {
    background: #ff5000;
    width: 600px;
        }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topbox {
    background: #9b4fe0;
    width: 300px;
        }
}
```

That way the first rule will apply to screens between 601 and 800px width, the second one to screens equal or less than 600px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Based on just that CSS, your `topbox` is a class not an id, therefore it should be `.topbox` instead of `#topbox`.

```
.topbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topbox {
    background: #9b4fe0;
    width: 300px;
        }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.topbox {
    background: #ff5000;
    width: 600px;
        }
}
```

Comment: Still dont think i have set the screen sizes right as its not displaying mobile  settings vs desktop settings. it only shows maxwidth 800 setting in mobile. And neither in desktop.

Comment: @mlolm try `@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px)` for desktop and see if that works. It has worked like that for me before.